# what is difference between while(true) and wait() or thread join()

Tags: java, multithreading, kotlin, while-loop, operating-system

I want to keep the main thread alive.
I found 3 options, and i wonder which one is the best.
what are the differences, and why??

is there any wasting resource among them?

1. while(true){}
2. thread.join()
3. CountDownLatch(1).await()

I tried them, and those worked well.

```java
while(true){}

thread.join()

CountDownLatch(1).await()
```

Comment: (2) and (3) are bad. (1) is awful.

Comment: Did you tagged kotlin for a good reason? Are you actually using kotlin? Then maybe coroutines would offer a better way to manage asynchrony / parallelism

Comment: @JonasWilms thank you!! ill try to look up the coroutine

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here:

```
while(true){}
```

does a "hot" wait. It means: your CPU spins at 100%, doing nothing. Maybe, maybe, if you are really lucky, the JVM detects that and is able to not burn CPU cycles like that.

Whereas, for join(), we find:

> When we invoke the join() method on a thread, the calling thread goes into a waiting state. It remains in a waiting state until the referenced thread terminates.

( from this [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-thread-join) )

So, join() sounds like the more healthy approach. `await()` should work in similar ways.

The downside of these two methods: they react to thread interrupts, so it might probably a good idea to put them into a "while true" loop.

Comment: i thought join() or wait() method is coded like while(true) loop....tried to find the code though i couldn't..

Comment: @aguagu No, they aren't. A *waiting* thread is **not** the same thing as a thread that sits there in a loop spinning the CPU with "nop" instructions.

Answer (score 3):

> is there any wasting resource among them?

An infinite loop definetly wastes ressources as it iterates for no reason, and consumes computation time and energy.

The other two should not waste ressources as they allow the OS to execute other threads in the meantime while they are blocked.

Answer (score 3):

None of them are adequate themselves.

```
while(true){}
```

Endless busy loop spins forever on the processor, generating heat and consuming elctricity. It can not be stopped cleanly.

```
thread.join()
```

Waiting for another thread to finish. This is different from the others because this can actually finish, instead of just running forever. But if the application consists solely of another thread running until it finishes, why not run the code from the main thread then, instead of creating another thread and waiting for it to finish?

```
CountDownLatch(1).await()
```

Creating a monitor and waiting for it forever. This is pretty much the same as:

```
Object o = new Object();
synchronized (o) {
    o.wait();
}
```

Again, there is no clean way to stop the program.

The last one, a CountdownLatch, would be closest to an approach that can be worked with. Instead of throwing away the reference to the latch immediately, pass it to the code that controls the execution so that it can tell the main thread that it is time to stop. But a CountdownLatch itself as a signal for exit condition is confusing. Exit signal is a boolean, so a Semaphore would be more suitable

```
Semaphore exitPermission = new Semaphore(0);
// Pass exit permission around.
exitPermission.acquire();
```

But this still allows the recipient to mess the state (by trying to acquire it and mess the scheduling), so the Semaphore should be hidden behind an interface that only allows others to release it.